# How to keep nested lists, which have a unique ID?

Tags: python, list, set

```
nested_list = [['123','hello','true'],['234','excuse','true'],['123,''hello','true'],['254','hello','false']]
```

I have a list of list. Each nested list has three values, an ID, and two text strings.

I want to keep only those nested lists that have an unique ID.

I tried making it a set however, if I make it a set then I will lose the fourth nested list which I want in the output as it's ID is unique.

```
output = [['123','hello','true'],['234','excuse','true'],['254','hello','false']]
```

How can I get this done?

Comment: Python Booleans, begin with a capital letter. `True` & `False`.

Comment: When you say "I want to keep only those nested lists that have unique ID" do you really mean "I want to keep the first/last nested list for each ID"? Otherwise, in your example output, the list `['123', 'hello', 'true']` should not appear since that ID appears twice in your input example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your inner list to tuple:

```
nested_list = [['123','hello','true'],['234','excuse','true'],['123','hello','true'],['254','hello','false']]


def f7(seq):
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    return [x for x in seq if not (tuple(x) in seen or seen_add(tuple(x)))]


print(f7(nested_list))
```

output:

```
[['123', 'hello', 'true'], ['234', 'excuse', 'true'], ['254', 'hello', 'false']]
```

Comment: will this change the order?

Comment: @user12204086 You want to maintain the order too?

Comment: This will produce duplicate IDs if the rest of the tuple is different. I don't think that's what the OP wants.

Comment: @user12204086: This will modify the order.

Comment: @user12204086 I have updated the answer, it won't change the order now.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Looks like we are in agreement - see comment that I added under my answer after noticing that it **partially** duplicated this one.

Comment: @alani your answer is more accurate. :)

Answer (score 1):

I mean, the simplest way is to just iterate across them and create a new list:

```
nested_list = [['123','hello','true'],
               ['234','excuse','true'],
               ['123','hello','true'],
               ['254','hello','false']]
visited_ids = set()
unique_nested_list = []
for thing in nested_list: 
  if thing[0] not in visited_ids:
    visited_ids.add(thing[0])
    unique_nested_list.append(thing)
print(unique_nested_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a list comprehension:

```
>>> nested_list = [['123','hello','true'],['234','excuse','true'],
                   ['123','hello','true'],['254','hello','false']]

>>> used = set()

>>> [a for a in nested_list if not (a[0] in used or used.add(a[0]))]
[['123', 'hello', 'true'], ['234', 'excuse', 'true'], ['254', 'hello', 'false']]
```

If the element already exists in the set `used`, then `a[0] in used` returns `True` (and the whole `not ...` returns `False`), hence the item is filtered out.  If it does not, then `a[0] in used` returns `False`, so the `used.add` is called -- adding it to the set -- and returning `None` (a "falsy" value), hence the `not ...` evaluates `True` and the item is included.

Comment: Note: I have seen after posting this that Chandan Kumar's answer also uses a list comprehension with a somewhat similar trick. However, I will leave this answer because that other answer tests whether the *entire sublist* has already been seen, which is not what is specified in the question (we only care whether we have seen the same ID before). The difference may become important if a sublist were to contain a ID that was already used, but with different values for one or both of the other items.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. I just missed that ID part in question.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to do this is to use the numpy.unique() function. It allows you to identify the index of unique elements. No loops are needed.

```
nested_list = [['123','hello','true'],['234','excuse','true'], 
   ['123','hello','true'],['254','hello','false']]

import numpy as np
arr = np.array(nested_list)
_ , idx = np.unique(arr[:,0],return_index = True)

print(arr[idx])
```

Output:

```
[['123' 'hello' 'true']
 ['234' 'excuse' 'true']
 ['254' 'hello' 'false']]
```